# phone gap splash screen stretch image

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I am trying to make a simple and accurate phonegap app. my splash screen is working but when i rotae the screen splash screen stretch

```
<gap:splash src="images/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"  gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="images/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"   gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="images/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="images/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"  gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all images for landscape too:

```
gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"
gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"
gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"
gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your replay i add that code  and add all land image in to image folder. first loading time land and port splash screen working  but when i rotate the mobile screen stretch and compress

Comment: Which version of Cordova/Phonegap are you using?

Comment: <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"   source="npm" spec="2.1.0" />

Comment: I think this can be a issue, try to update your cordova/phonegap and the splashscreen plugin.